# Update large MySQL table as fast as posible

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty large table (4.5 million records) and on each record I do have an column with an IP and another column(empty) where I should write the country for that IP. I also have another table with IP ranges and country for that specific range, so I can know what country correspond to specific ip. So far I'm using the following code:

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN ipcountry ON  INET_ATON(table1.clientIp) > INET_ATON(ipcountry.start)
SET 
table1.country = ipcountry.country
WHERE
    INET_ATON(table1.clientIp) > INET_ATON(ipcountry.start)
AND
    INET_ATON(table1.clientIp) < INET_ATON(ipcountry.end)
AND 
table1.country = ''
```

By using this code I get updated like 300 rows every minute(which is way to slow). Can anyone recommend me an faster way or can explain me why this is running so slow?

Comment: You are constantly converting IP's. What about creating an adicional column on both tables with the `INET_ATON(ip)`? That way you only need a previous update that converts the IP once (and could remain there if you need to use it). And those country updates would be faster.

Comment: Overall is the same thing. The biggest issue is that I'm doing some inner join with two big table (4.5 mil rows with 300k rows). I will do some test anyway

Comment: One could save the convertion of ip into a variable. instead of doing double work. You do so within the `where` statement and in the `AND` statement for the same ip.